# How to sort and query the varchar type approximate-value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to ask about mysql.

table aname - **bio_tb**
column name / column type - **no number, name varchar, result varchar, e_value varchar**

1   aaa   result1   1e-3
2   aaa   result2   2e-4
3   bbb   result3   3e-6
4   bbb   result4   4e-5

**question 1)**
1   aaa   result1   0.001
2   aaa   result2   0.0002
3   bbb   result3   0.000003
4   bbb   result4   0.00004

e_value is stored in varchar type.
Is there any way to change this to real value like 0.001?

if difficult,
any way for sorting through coverting/casting the varchar value to float/double value?

**Question 2)**
1   aaa   result1   0.001
4   bbb   result4   0.00004

I want result like this (rows having group min or max).
Is there any way to use group function for this result other than subquery?


mysql version is 5.1.30.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally on this site if you have more than one question it's better to post them as separate questions. You might be better to edit this one and then post your second question separately.

Comment: Thank you. from next time, I will post separately.

Comment: I found the answer myself. for sorting, I used order by 0+e_value and for result, subquery.